# How to differentiate the continuous and non-continuous date ranges based on ID column

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

```
ID  STRT_DT, ENT_DT 
1 9/14/2020,10/5/2020
1 10/6/2020,10/8/2020
1 10/9/2020,12/31/2199
2 7/14/2020,11/5/2020
2 11/21/2020,11/22/2020
2 11/23/2020,12/31/2199
```

Upon observing the above data for ID 1 and 2, The date ranges belongs to 1 are continuous and the ID 2 are non-continuous . I need pull the ID's which are continuous in SQL.
Expected o/p : If any of the date range is not continuous (grouping by ID), that should not come into select clause. So the expectation of the SQL output is to get ID=1

Query using:

```
SELECT tab.ID,TAB.STRT_DT,TAB.ENT_DT,
STRT_DT - MIN(ENT_DT) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ENT_DT ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS diff, 
ENT_DT - MAX(STRT_DT) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ENT_DT ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS diff2 
FROM  tabLE QUALIFY diff <> 1 OR diff2 <> -1
```

Comment: Are you using Oracle or Teradata?

Comment: Instead of `ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING` you may use `RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '1' DAY PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '1' DAY PRECEDING`

Comment: @jarlh I am using Teradata

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Order by clause is not working with RANGE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ID
from
 (
   select 
      ID, 
      -- flag non-continous ranges, i.e. previous end is not equal to the day before current start
      case when STRT_DT - 1
            <> LAG(ENT_DT) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY STRT_DT)
           then 1
           else 0
      end as flag
   from table
 ) as dt
group by ID
having sum(flag) = 0 -- only continous ranges exist
```

Comment: That's worked and solved my problem. Thanks for Quick response and your time

Answer (score 0):

You can use self join without window function.

```
select t1.id,
       t2.start_dt prev_start_dt, t2.end_dt prev_end_dt,
       t1.start_dt, t1.end_dt,
       to_date(t1.start_dt, 'MM/DD/YYYY') - to_date(t2.end_dt, 'MM/DD/YYYY') diff
from   t t1 inner join t t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where  to_date(t1.start_dt, 'MM/DD/YYYY') - to_date(t2.end_dt, 'MM/DD/YYYY') = 1
order by t1.id, t1.start_dt
```

Result:

```
ID  PREV_START_DT   PREV_END_DT START_DT    END_DT  DIFF
1   9/14/2020   10/5/2020   10/6/2020   10/8/2020   1
1   10/6/2020   10/8/2020   10/9/2020   12/31/2199  1
2   11/21/2020  11/22/2020  11/23/2020  12/31/2199  1
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e20d48300f81e746826e44d8ee6982be

---

If you want to get only ID that all rows continued, you can use left join to see joined row and not joined row.

```
select t1.id
from   t t1 left join t t2 
            on t1.id = t2.id
            and to_date(t1.start_dt, 'MM/DD/YYYY') - to_date(t2.end_dt, 'MM/DD/YYYY') = 1
group by t1.id
having count(t1.id) - 1 = count(t2.id)
```

Result:

```
ID
1
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=85679be30f170e3728d7e8b0b0da533e

Comment: I want to select only the ID's that are having continuous date ranges. As per the above provided data samples. I want a SQL which will fetch ID=1 in select clause. Kindly help

Comment: `select distinct t1.id
from   t t1 inner join t t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where  to_date(t1.start_dt, 'MM/DD/YYYY') - to_date(t2.end_dt, 'MM/DD/YYYY') = 1
order by 1` This selects only id. In addition, I think second to third of ID 2 is also continued.

Comment: If any of the date range is not continuous (grouping by ID), that should not come into select clause. So the expectation of the SQL output is to get ID=1

Comment: @Shankar Oh, I see. I appended answer you want.